# Поддержка UTF-8 в JDBC соединении к MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script

При записи в базу данных строк, содержащих кириллицу, отображаются знаки неверной кодировки:

```
var connection = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://...", "...", "...");
var stmt = connection.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO test (Nam, Fam, Rost, HB) values ('Иван','Петрович', '200', '2000-02-02')");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На изображении выше показаны записи, созданные через phpAdmin (первые три) и через Google Apps Script (последняя).

Текущая кодировка `varchar (utf8_general_ci)`.

Использование префикса `N` для совместимости кодировок результатов не даёт.

Используемый код:

```
var stmt = connection.createStatement()
  .execute("INSERT INTO\
            test (Nam, Fam, Rost, HB)\
            values (N'Иван',N'Петрович', '200', '2000-02-02')");
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на _Stackoverflow на русском_! На этом сайте нужно задавать вопросы на русском языке

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете попробовать использовать дополнительные параметры в строке подключения

```
jdbc:mysql://host:port/instance?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```